# iterate over array count even numbers, print number of counts and even numbers in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift

```
import UIKit


var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for myInt: Int in myArray{
//counts numbers in array
for i in 0..<myArray.count{
    //to find even number
    if myInt % 2 == 0 {


        print("Record Number \(i): \(myInt)")
}}}
```

it prints out each even number 10 times and I only need it to print counts: even number.

Comment: Add a "counter" variable that will add +1 each time you encounter an even number. Once the for loop ended, print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to count how much elements matching condition which is in your case if number is even (`number % 2 == 0`) and then you need to print it.

To achieve this, first get number of these elements which matching condition and then print this number.

To keep it simple to understand I will keep your for each loop

```
var matching = 0

for myInt in myArray {

    if myInt % 2 == 0 {
        matching += 1 // if number matching condition, increase count of matching elements
    }

}

print(number)
```

---

Anyway you can make it much easier using for example count on filtered items (it counts how many elements were filtered)

```
let matching = myArray.filter({ $0 % 2 == 0 }).count
```

or you can use `reduce` which increase initial value every time that element matching condition

```
let matching = myArray.reduce(0) { $1 % 2 == 0 ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```

---

For the future: In Swift 5 you can use newly introduced method [`count(where:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md) which counts number of elements which matching condition

```
let matching = myArray.count(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a such a detailed explanation